# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when trying generate an .ipa

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using xcode and I have the following error ONLY when I try generate an .ipa vía `Product->Archive`

```
Ld /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Sonrie.build/Release-iphoneos/SonrieTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SonrieTests normal armv7
    cd /Users/Ricardo/Documents/XCode/clickmobile-sonrie-ios/Sonrie
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk -L/Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/Ricardo/Documents/XCode/clickmobile-sonrie-ios/Sonrie/RealEstateFinder/Libraries/FacebookSDK -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Sonrie.build/Release-iphoneos/SonrieTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SonrieTests.LinkFileList -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Sonrie.app/Sonrie -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Sonrie.build/Release-iphoneos/SonrieTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SonrieTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Sonrie.build/Release-iphoneos/SonrieTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SonrieTests

ld: file not found: /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Sonrie.app/Sonrie
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


ld: file not found: /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Sonrie.app/Sonrie


ld: file not found: /Users/Ricardo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sonrie-dqppheybmvzqpqdxnrdfabtefhwh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Sonrie/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Sonrie.app/Sonrie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solve it!.
My Test Product Name was not the same to my Project Product Name.

Comment: I ran into the same thing -- under Build Settings for the tests, I had to change the Test Host from `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/OldName.app/OldName` to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/NewName.app/NewName`